# CUDA parallel computing speed up volume calculation

Tags: c++, performance, cuda

- Device : Tesla C2050
- OS     : Windows 7 Enterprise
- IDE    : VS 2010
- CUDA   : 5.0 (newest)

First time to ask question here. I met some problems in my CUDA program.

I have millions tetrahedrons with one point at (0,0,0), so I can use the formula:

to get the volume of the tetrahedrons.

So , here is the code:

```
struct Triangle
{
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double z1;
    double x2;
    double y2;
    double z2;
    double x3;
    double y3;
    double z3;
};
```

And the CUDA code:

```
__global__ void getResult(double *d_volume ,Triangle *d_triangles, Origin *d_point)
{
    extern __shared__ Triangle s_data[];
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int i =  blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    s_data[tid] = d_triangles[i];
    __syncthreads();
    d_volume[i] =s_data[tid].x1 * s_data[tid].y2 * s_data[tid].z3 + \
                s_data[tid].y1 * s_data[tid].z2 * s_data[tid].x3 + \
                s_data[tid].x2 * s_data[tid].y3 * s_data[tid].z1 - \
                s_data[tid].x3 * s_data[tid].y2 * s_data[tid].z1 - \
                s_data[tid].x2 * s_data[tid].y1 * s_data[tid].z3 - \
                s_data[tid].y3 * s_data[tid].z2 * s_data[tid].x1;
}
```

I got millions of tetrahedrons from other function as an array.

```
// Host
Triangle *h_triangles = triangles;
double *h_volume;
// Device
Triangle *d_triangles;
double *d_volume;

// define grid and block size
int numThreadsPerBlock = numTriangles;
int numBlocks = numTrianges / 512;

// Shard memory size
int sharedMemSize = numThreadsPerBlock * sizeof(Triangle);

// allocate host and device memory
size_t memSize_triangles = numBlocks * numThreadsPerBlock * sizeof(Triangle);
size_t memSize_volume = numBlocks * numThreadsPerBlock * sizeof(double);

cudaMalloc( (void **) &d_triangles, memSize_triangles );
cudaMalloc( (void **) &d_volume, memSize_volume );

// Copy host array to device array
cudaMemcpy( d_triangles, h_triangles, memSize_triangles, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
cudaMemcpy( d_point, h_point, memSize_point, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

// launch kernel
dim3 dimGrid(numBlocks);
dim3 dimBlock(numThreadsPerBlock);

getResult<<< dimGrid, dimBlock, sharedMemSize >>>( d_volume, d_triangles);

// block until the device has completed
cudaThreadSynchronize();

// device to host copy
cudaMemcpy( h_volume, d_volume, memSize_volume, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

// free device memory
cudaFree(d_triangles);
cudaFree(d_volume);

// free host memory
free(h_triangles); 
free(h_volume);
```

Up to now, everything works OK. But I cost more time than I thought to get the volume.
My device is Tesla C2050(515Gflops), 20 times faster than my CPU(single-core, 20.25Gflops).
But only speed up about 10 times (not including the time copying memory between device and host.)

I'd like to know how can I make it about 20 times faster than the CPU code (for loop to get the volume.).

Thanks!

PS: Maybe cudaMallocPitch() will help me, but the triangles are not matrix, I can't use cudaMemcpy2D() to copy memory instead of cudaMemcpy(). Anyone who can help me about this question?

Comment: Have you tried any compiler optimization?

Comment: @kumar_m_kiran I haven't tried any compiler optimization, can you tell me how to make it or show me some links to read. Thanks!

Comment: How do you get the number '40x'?

Comment: @Eric Thanks for your answer. My CPU(single-core) is about 20.24GFlops,and Tesla C2050 is 515Gflops. So, sorry, it's about 20x times.

Comment: Could you also provide some profiling result?

Comment: @Eric Sorry I have no other profiling result. The only one I have is when I calculating 1024 * 1024 * 16 triangles, it costs 64ms on GPU, but 648ms on my CPU.

Comment: Why does your kernel use shared memory for? There doesn't seem to be any obvious reason to do so, and it will be faster not to use it

Comment: @talonmies Using shared memory speed up 3-4 times than I didn't use it. I thought when I'm using shared memory, it only need to access global memory once per block, threads can access shared memory instead of global memory. I don't know whether it is correct. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peak performance on GPU usually harder to get compared to CPU. One of the reason is that a lot of kernels are bandwidth-bound rather than computing-bound.

Since your kernel's computing complexity is O(n). You probably should use bandwidth metric to calculate the theoretical peak performance as follows

```
1024*1024*64 * sizeof(double) * (9  +   1)     / (144e9    *    8/9)     = 42 ms
#tetrahedron                     #input #output   peak mem bw   ECC cost
```

On the other hand, your kernel could be further optimized.

- Choose blockDim/gridDim carefully, wrong numbers sometimes result in 20% performance lost.
- Instead of computing **one** volume per thread, you could computing **multiple** volumes per thread, which will reduce the thread launching overhead.
- Since you don't share data between threads, `__syncthreads()` may be able to eliminated.
- Array of Structures (AoS) often slower than Structure of Arrays (SoA) on GPU due to non-coalesced mem access. you could also try to change your data structure.

### Update

Got a new kernel with large L1 cache setup and best blockDim/gridDim choice. It's 15% faster. Here's the code and profile result. My device is M2090.

[image: profile result]

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <iterator>
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;

struct Triangle
{
    double x1;
    double y1;
    double z1;
    double x2;
    double y2;
    double z2;
    double x3;
    double y3;
    double z3;
};

__global__ void getResultNoSMem(double *d_volume, Triangle *d_triangles)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    d_volume[i] = d_triangles[i].x1 * d_triangles[i].y2 * d_triangles[i].z3 +
            d_triangles[i].y1 * d_triangles[i].z2 * d_triangles[i].x3 +
            d_triangles[i].x2 * d_triangles[i].y3 * d_triangles[i].z1 -
            d_triangles[i].x3 * d_triangles[i].y2 * d_triangles[i].z1 -
            d_triangles[i].x2 * d_triangles[i].y1 * d_triangles[i].z3 -
            d_triangles[i].y3 * d_triangles[i].z2 * d_triangles[i].x1;
}

__global__ void getResult(double *d_volume, Triangle *d_triangles)
{
    extern __shared__ Triangle s_data[];
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    s_data[tid] = d_triangles[i];
//  __syncthreads();
    d_volume[i] = s_data[tid].x1 * s_data[tid].y2 * s_data[tid].z3 +
            s_data[tid].y1 * s_data[tid].z2 * s_data[tid].x3 +
            s_data[tid].x2 * s_data[tid].y3 * s_data[tid].z1 -
            s_data[tid].x3 * s_data[tid].y2 * s_data[tid].z1 -
            s_data[tid].x2 * s_data[tid].y1 * s_data[tid].z3 -
            s_data[tid].y3 * s_data[tid].z2 * s_data[tid].x1;
}

__global__ void getResultOpt(double *d_volume, Triangle *d_triangles, int len)
{
    const int gridSize = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    while (i < len)
    {
        d_volume[i] = d_triangles[i].x1 * d_triangles[i].y2 * d_triangles[i].z3 +
                d_triangles[i].y1 * d_triangles[i].z2 * d_triangles[i].x3 +
                d_triangles[i].x2 * d_triangles[i].y3 * d_triangles[i].z1 -
                d_triangles[i].x3 * d_triangles[i].y2 * d_triangles[i].z1 -
                d_triangles[i].x2 * d_triangles[i].y1 * d_triangles[i].z3 -
                d_triangles[i].y3 * d_triangles[i].z2 * d_triangles[i].x1;
        i += gridSize;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const int m = 1024 * 1024;
    thrust::host_vector<Triangle> data(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        data[i].x1 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        data[i].y1 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        data[i].z1 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        data[i].x2 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        data[i].y2 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        data[i].z2 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        data[i].x3 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        data[i].y3 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        data[i].z3 = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;
    }

    thrust::device_vector<Triangle> triangles = data;
    thrust::device_vector<double> volume(m);
    thrust::device_vector<double> volumeOpt(m);

    Triangle* dTriangles = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&triangles[0]);
    double* dVolume = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&volume[0]);
    double* dVolumeOpt = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&volumeOpt[0]);

    int g;
    int b;

    int threadUpperLimit = 48 * 1024 / sizeof(Triangle);

    //for (b = 32; b <= 1024; b += 32)
    {
        b = 64;
        int gridDim = (m + b - 1) / b;
        getResultNoSMem<<<gridDim, b, 0, 0>>>(dVolume, dTriangles);
    }

    //  for (b = 32; b <= threadUpperLimit; b += 32)
    {
        b = 64;
        int gridDim = (m + b - 1) / b;
        getResult<<<gridDim, b, b * sizeof(Triangle), 0>>>(dVolume, dTriangles);
    }

    //for (g = 32; g <= 512; g += 32)
    //  for (b = 32; b <= 1024; b += 32)
    {
        b = 64;
        g = 64;
        getResultOpt<<<g, b, 0, 0>>>(dVolumeOpt, dTriangles, m);
    }

    //for (g = 32; g <= 512; g += 32)
    //  for (b = 32; b <= 1024; b += 32)
    {
        b = 64;
        g = 512;
        cudaFuncSetCacheConfig(getResultOpt, cudaFuncCachePreferL1);
        getResultOpt<<<g, b, 0, 0>>>(dVolumeOpt, dTriangles, m);
    }

    thrust::device_vector<double> X = volume;
    thrust::device_vector<double> Y = volumeOpt;
    thrust::transform(X.begin(), X.end(), Y.begin(), X.begin(), _1 - _2);
    double result = thrust::inner_product(X.begin(), X.end(), X.begin(), 0.0);

    std::cout << "difference: " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 1. As I used shared mem, it speed up 3 - 4 times than I didn't use it. 2. I will remove __syncthreads(), thank you. 3. I have read some samples when I learning CUDA programing, these samples using array point, so I used it too. Will vector work better? Thank you again!

Comment: You could refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179426/how-to-structure-data-for-optimal-speed-in-a-cuda-app for the concept of SoA and AoS

Comment: Remove __syncthreads() made a 10% speed up. (64ms -> 57ms for 1024 * 1024 * 16 triangles). Thank you!And It's interesting when I didn't use share memory in my kernel code,(without extern __shared__ Triangle s_data[];...), using getResult<<< dimGrid, dimBlock, sharedMemSize >>>( d_volume, d_triangles); will be faster than getResult<<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>( d_volume, d_triangles); (The former is 66ms and the latter is 170ms). Can you tell me why?

Comment: @ZavierXu Not using shared mem as cache will increase the global mem read from 9 per thread to 18 per thread, which will reduce the performance. Although device L1 cache will automatically handle this situation, it is still not as good as set the cache manually.

Comment: @Eric: You are going to have to explain that comment? Why would the number of reads *increase*?

Comment: First assume that there's no cache on the device. Without shared mem, you read from `d_triangles` 18*sizeof(double) bytes global mem to compute one `volume`. With shared mem, you read `d_triangles` 9*sizeof(double)  bytes global mem, save them in shared mem then repeatly use them. And the time of reading from shared mem is much less then the time of reading from global mem.

Comment: I don't think we are looking at the same code. In both cases, a single volume output is computed from a single `Triangle` input, which is loaded from global memory - 9 double precision loads. The only difference in the shared memory case is that the loads are copied to shared memory and then loaded back to registers. There is no shared memory reuse in this code between threads. Compile the kernel and have a look at the PTX for yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: To compute one volume, you use .x1 twice, right? So I think shared mem is reused **in** the thread. What is the situation would be if your don't use shared mem?

Comment: @Eric: the whole structure is loaded into registers in both cases. The only difference is that the shared version loads into shared memory, and from shared memory into registers, rather directly.

Comment: @talonmies I didn't see the PTX. There's only 64 bytes register per thread for CC 2.0 device. But the data has 72 bytes. And my profiling shows the kernel only uses 25~30 bytes register per thread. I thought they can not be loaded into registers all together.

Comment: Eh? 64 registers per thread. A CUDA register is 32bit. The whole structure of 9 doubles requires 18 registers.

Comment: @Eric I guess you are using fedora, am I right? It seems that the last function works best, I will have a try tomorrow. I should ask question here earlier, I have suffered for 2 weeks in this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Eric Hi Eric, Thanks for your help. I have tested hundreds numbers of threads and blocks, with **multi-calculations in one thread**, I finally made 25 times faster than the normal CPU(single-core). Set bigger numbers of registers and find right number of DimBlock and DimGrid are very important, which made the code 200% faster than the old one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Eric Hi Eric, do you know anything about OpenCL? I did the same thing on OpenCL, it(without optimization) works as quickly as the CUDA code(optimized). Does it mean that OpenCL is better than CUDA? What I noticed is OpenCL code use 22 registers in one thread but CUDA only use 12.

Comment: @ZavierXu never used before. just like c v.s. fortran, you can not tell which one is better.

Comment: @Eric Yeah, you're right. We only can say OpenCL support AMD cards but CUDA not. Thanks any way~

Answer (score 1):

As Eric's answer implies, your kernel requires nine 64 bit loads and a 64 bit store per thread, but each thread only performs 17 FLOP. That probably means your code is memory bandwidth limited, rather than compute limited, and you shouldn't expect to be able to hit peak FLOP/s throughput for a code of this type.

The key to optimal performance will, therefore, most likely be in memory bandwidth optimization. At the moment, your kernel has several obvious problems, one of which I touched on in a comment. You really don't need shared memory in the kernel as written - it is slower than registers and there is no memory bandwidth improvements to be had by using it. The use of `__syncthreads()` also adds unnecessary latency to the kernel. You code could be written as simply as this:

```
__global__ void getresult2(double *d_volume, Triangle *d_triangles)
{
    int i =  blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    Triangle t = d_triangles[i];
    d_volume[i] = t.x1 * t.y2 * t.z3 + 
                  t.y1 * t.z2 * t.x3 +
                  t.x2 * t.y3 * t.z1 -
                  t.x3 * t.y2 * t.z1 -
                  t.x2 * t.y1 * t.z3 - 
                  t.y3 * t.z2 * t.x1;
}
```

[disclaimer, never compiled or run, use at own risk]

and I would expect it to perform better than the shared memory version.

The second problem is one of memory coalescing. The structure you have is rather large, and each thread loading a complete instance of `Triangle` won't be very friendly to memory coalescing or cache reuse. You could try using shared memory to improve the memory load performance and coalesce the writes by doing something like this:

```
__global__ 
void __launch_bounds__(288, 3)getresult3(double *d_volume, Triangle *d_triangles)
{
    __shared__ double s_data[9*32];

    int i =  blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    double * t_data = reinterpret_cast<double *>(d_triangles);
    s_data[threadIdx.x] = t_data[i];
    __syncthreads();

    if (threadIdx.x < 32) {
        Triangle * t = reinterpret_cast<Triangle *>(&s_data[9*threadIdx.x]);
        d_volume[i] = t->x1 * t->y2 * t->z3 + 
            t->y1 * t->z2 * t->x3 +
            t->x2 * t->y3 * t->z1 -
            t->x3 * t->y2 * t->z1 -
            t->x2 * t->y1 * t->z3 - 
            t->y3 * t->z2 * t->x1;
    }
}
```

[disclaimer, never compiled or run, use at own risk]

Here, the block of 288 threads fetches 32 `Triangle` instances to shared memory in a coalesced load, then the first 32 threads in the block perform the calculations and store 32 results. A scheme like this *might* prove faster if the kernel is really not achieving a very high fraction of global memory bandwdith throughput. The CUDA toolkit profiling tools have some rather useful performance metric analysis which can help pinpoint the performance bottlenecks in your code. Like all optimization exercises, the key is careful profiling and benchmarking, which is something only you are in a position to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can understand the first code, `Triangle t = d_triangles[i];` I think it is much better than my stupid code. But I'm not quite understand the second code, I'm not familiar with `__launch_bounds__(288,3)` and `reinterpret_cast`... Your explaination is helpful. I will try both code and tell you the result. Thanks again.

Comment: Remove `__syncthreads()` made a 10% speed up. (64ms -> 57ms for 1024 * 1024 * 16 triangles). Thank you!

Comment: It's interesting when I didn't use share memory in my kernel code,(without `extern __shared__ Triangle s_data[];...`), using `getResult<<< dimGrid, dimBlock, sharedMemSize >>>( d_volume, d_triangles);` will be faster than `getResult<<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>( d_volume, d_triangles);` (The former is 66ms and the latter is 170ms). Can you tell me why?

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure how to use the second code. Should I change the number of shared memory as `int sharedMemSize = 288 * sizeof(double);` and the launch code as `getresult3<<< dimGrid, 288, sharedMemSize >>> (d_volume, d_triangles);`? When I tried to run the code, it crashed when launch the kernel with a kernel invocation error.

Comment: The second code doesn't need any external shared memory. Just launch it with 288 threads per block and (number of triangles / 32) blocks in the grid.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have a try tomorrow. BTW, does "__align__ (16) " works on global memory in this case?